# python asyncio active loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, cryptocurrency

I've been looking into asyncio topics a while now, but have never really found what I am looking for.

Basically I am developing a trading bot in python that should listen to trade opportunities which are held in for example MySQL.

So it needs to query MySQL every x seconds, and if there are any jobs to be started then start a job for it until finished

With the following code I simulate a new opportunity every time the while loop is done:

```
    import asyncio, time

    async def trade_task(counter):
        print('task here')
        time.sleep(20)
        print('sleep for testing purposes to keep the instance running')
        print('more tasks here')

    counter = 0
    while True:

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        task = loop.create_task(trade_task(counter))

        print('hier')

        try:
            loop.run_until_complete(task)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

        counter += 1
        time.sleep(10)
```

it kinda works, but it now waits for the trade_task function to finish, until proceeding and finishing the first run of the while loop.

I need something that created a task for trade_task in the background, and immediately proceed to check for another opportunity.

- periodic check to see if there is an opportunity
- if entry found, start task in background and keep looking for opportunity
- if entry found, start task in background and keep looking for opportunity

I've done this through threading before, but can asyncio do this better?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there should only be one primary event loop and all your tasks should run there,

Try something like this,

```py
import asyncio
from itertools import count


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)


async def trade_task(counter):
    print('task here')
    # time.sleep is a blocking call and halts the execution of other tasks in the loop as well.
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    print('sleep for testing purposes to keep the instance running')
    print('more tasks here')

    
async def task_spawner():
    # if you want an infinite loop
    for counter in count():
        # this new task would run in bg
        loop.create_task(trade_task(counter))
        # While this one sleeps
        await asyncio.sleep(20)

    # if you have a fixed counter range (e.g. 10)
    # all run parallelly here
    await asyncio.gather(*(trade_task(counter) for for counter in range(10)))
        

loop.run_until_complete(task_spawner())
```